# Equivalent definition of R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am studying a course of Commutative Algebra and I'm having trouble understanding an alternative definition of R-module. The standard definition is the following:

Let $R$ be a ring (commutative, with unity). An $R$–module is an
abelian group $(M, +)$ together with a map 
\begin{align*}
&R \times M \rightarrow  M\\
&(r, m) \mapsto r ∗ m =: rm \in M
\end{align*}

satisfying the following conditions:

1. $(r + s)m = rm + sm$ for all $r, s \in R, m \in M.$
2. $r(m + n) = rm + rn$ for all $r \in R, m, n \in M$.
3. $(rs)m = r(sm)$ for all $r, s \in R, m \in M$.
4. For all $m \in M$ one has $1m = m$

In my lectures notes it is said that the definition above is equivalent to the existence of a ring homomorphism

\begin{align*}
&f:R \rightarrow End(M)&
\end{align*}

where $End(M)$ is the endomorphism ring of $M$

Here it comes my approach and where I'm stuck:

$\left( \impliedby \right)$:

Suppose there exists a ring homomorphism

\begin{align*}
&f: R \rightarrow End(M)&\\
& r \mapsto \lambda_{r}
\end{align*}

Then, we define

\begin{align*}
&R \times M \rightarrow M \\
&(r, m) \mapsto \lambda_{r}(m)
\end{align*}

We have to check that this map satisfies properties $(1-4)$:

We have $1$ since $f$ is a ring homomorphism.

We have $1$ since $\lambda_{r}$ is a group homomorphism.

We have $4$ since $1_{A}$ goes to $1_{End(M)}$ by $f$.

However, I am unable to prove $3$. I've tried using all the properties available, but I just can't see it.

$\left( \implies \right)$

This time, we define the ring homomorphism as it follows:

\begin{align*}
&f:R \rightarrow End(M)\\
&r \mapsto \lambda_{r}
\end{align*}

where

\begin{align*}
\lambda_{r}: M \rightarrow M\\
m \mapsto rm
\end{align*}

$f(r+s)=f(r)+f(s)$ is easy to see, using property $1$ of $M$ as $R-module$.

$f(1)=1$ because of property $4$.

Here, I also struggle, because I cannot proof $f(rs)=f(r)f(s)$.

---

I'd be very grateful if anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

PD: Sorry for the writing of the maps. I'm new here and I'm not used to the language.

Comment: Might be worthy to check [Representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory) wiki. This is almost the same, just that in your case one doesn't represent ring as linear maps of vector spaces, but endomorphisms of abelian groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\implies$, 3): doesn't this follow from the fact that $f$ is a ring homomorphism, as in your verification of 1)?

$\impliedby$, $f(rs)=f(r)f(s)$: similarly, this follows from property 3)

---

Perhaps it may be good to emphasize that the <s>group operation</s> ring multiplication in $End(M)$ is function composition. That is, $\lambda_r \cdot \lambda_s$ applied to $m$ is $\lambda_r(\lambda_s(m))$, which in your case is $m \mapsto rsm$.

Comment: That is totally the point. Somehow, I had forgotten that the group operation in $End(M)$ is function composition (I was trying to use usual product). Thanks!!

Comment: Probably, *ring multiplication*, not *group operation*. $\mathbb{End}(M)$ generally does not form a group.

Comment: @lisyarus Good point, thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

For the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction, 3 follows from ring homomorphism properties: $(rs)m = \lambda_{rs}(m)=(\lambda_r \circ \lambda_s)(m) = \lambda_r(\lambda_s(m)) = r(sm)$

Here, the second equality is a property of ring homomorphisms.

The other direction is similar.

Answer (score 0):

thinking where your difficulty might have come from, it is perhaps worth mentioning as a footnote to your question that in this context we must distinguish the abelian group endomorphisms of $M$, which may be denoted by $End_{\mathbb{Z}}M$, from the $R$-module endomorphisms of $M$, which may be denoted $End_R M$.

condition (3) is the requirement for an abelian group endomorphism. to be an $R$-module endomorphism imposes the further requirement that:
$$
r(s(m)) = sr(m)
$$
which is not always satisfied when $R$ is not commutative